# Rails ActiveStorage - Uploaded image throws error 400 after 5 minutes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

So I've heard a lot about Rails 5.2 and ActiveStorage, and there was a lot of talk about ActiveStorage being a drop in replacement for image handling in rails.

My issue is, I've set it up and upgraded my app. I upload an image, it goes to my Google Cloud storage bucket, and that's all fine.

The issue is, In my view I've tried stuff like:

```
   <%= image_tag((current_user.avatar), size: "100x100") %>
```

and

```
<%= image_tag(rails_blob_path(current_user.avatar, disposition: "attachment"), size: "100x100") %>
```

These will show the uploaded image for about 5 minutes, then the vanish from my view. If I inspect, it says error 400. How can I solve this?
I want my users avatars to be showing up permanently, not going away.

Please suggest, been searching and reading for hours about how to solve this.

edit: doing "open image in new tab" results in this XML error

```
<Error>
<Code>ExpiredToken</Code>
<Message>The provided token has expired.</Message>
<Details>
Request signature expired at: 2018-10-09T20:50:09+00:00
</Details>
</Error>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default expiry of image urls is 5 minutes (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#linking-to-files)

You can probably set a new key `url_expires_in` in your active storage config for google cloud services

Comment: This can be avoided altogether if you use a service_url, right?

Comment: I doubt if it will help because it will also use the same timeout, plus it is not recommended to be used directly, see documentation here:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb#L120

Comment: The images haven't expired yet.. is this a bug then?

Comment: The images url that is generated for you, does it point to your app or does it point to the google cloud?

Comment: That is strange, I will have to dig deeper then to see how it bypasses expiration flags

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use service_url to persist images in your applications views.

For example: `<%= image_tag(@user.avatar.service_url) %>`